# adding an environment variable in .zshrc on macOS Sonoma

Tags: macos

I am trying to set an API_KEY in .zshrc as follows:

export API_KEY='XXXXXX'

Once I do this and run

source ./.zshrc

I can see it echo $API_KEY

However, if I close the terminal and start a new terminal it is no longer there.

Why is the parameter not getting set on a new terminal?

I need to do source ./.zshrc again each time?

Comment: Keep it at `~/.zshrc` — you might’ve been putting it in different directory than user home.

Comment: Also, are you sure that ZSH is your default shell? In case it is Bash, you might want to change it using the `chsh` command.

Comment: You nailed it PieterT2000! Thank you so much for your quick response. I feel like an idiot ;-) My default shell was set as bash. Doh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to PieterT2000 in the comment.

The problem was that my default shell was set as bash.

Changing per PeterT2000's instructions i.e. using the chsh command fixed this for me.